# Ruby test suite creation

Tags: ruby

Need help in test suite creation/execute via test/unit in Ruby.
I have two test cases which are defined in a class and the class has a single method. The class inherits from Test::Unit::TestCase.  What I want to achieve is when I run my test suite, the methods in the class should be called and the results should be printed, however when I run my test suite the following is printed

```
Test::Unit::TestSuite::STARTED
Test::Unit::TestSuite::STARTED::OBJECT
Test::Unit::TestSuite::STARTED
Test::Unit::TestSuite::STARTED::OBJECT
Test::Unit::TestSuite::FINISHED

Test::Unit::TestSuite::FINISHED::OBJECT
Test::Unit::TestSuite::STARTED
Test::Unit::TestSuite::STARTED::OBJECT
Test::Unit::TestSuite::FINISHED
Test::Unit::TestSuite::FINISHED::OBJECT
Test::Unit::TestSuite::FINISHED
Test::Unit::TestSuite::FINISHED::OBJECT
```

Tried searching, but couldn’t find any solution.

```
require 'test/unit'
require 'test/unit/testcase'
require 'test/unit/ui/console/testrunner'
require 'test/unit/testsuite'
require 'test/unit/testresult'

class TC_HelloWorld < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def hello
    puts "Hello world!"
  end
end    
class TC_HelloWorld1 < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def hello
    puts "Hello1"
  end
end
class TS_HelloWorld
  def self.suite()
    suite = Test::Unit::TestSuite::new
    suite << TC_HelloWorld.suite
    suite << TC_HelloWorld1.suite

    return suite
  end
end

tr = Test::Unit::TestResult::new

TS_HelloWorld.suite.run(tr) do|result|
  puts(result)
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prefix your test methods with the string `test_`.  For example:

```
class TC_HelloWorld < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_hello                          # method name updated here
    puts "Hello world!"
  end
end
```

This is reflected in the [documentation](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/test-unit/2.4.7/Test/Unit): "Add a method that begins with “test” to your class.".